# Crystal Reports - How to get rid of empty fields?

Tags: c#, .net, crystal-reports

Let's say I have two fields (one under another). By default I want to have both of them rendered, but when the first field is empty, I would like the second one to take its place. Is there any convenient way to achieve this?

Note: My problem is much more complex, and a "scalable" solution would be highly appreciated.

I've found a cumbersome [method](http://forums.asp.net/t/1224925.aspx?How+to+supress+blank+space+in+the+crystal+report), but I'm still looking for something better.

Comment: You can achieve it using if else condition for each and every formula

Comment: I think if you show us some of the data and describe a bit more your problem, there should be some better solution without using sub-reports (sometimes sub-reports are kinda slow, so i try to avoid them).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally came up with a better solution. The solution is to create a table in a DataSet, and insert a subreport selecting the table as its data source. Now you can add rows dynamically to the table (depending on some conditions).